# Android:I do not understand: static { foo();}

Tags: java, android, static, static-block

Sometimes I see something like it, in a class in Android:

```
static
{
    foo();
}
```

- What does this do?
- Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a `static` block. It is executed the first time that class is referenced on your code, and it is calling a static method called `foo()`. You can find more about the static block [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). As mentioned by @CommonsWare, you can initialize a static field in two different ways, inline a declaration time

```
static ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("A");
    add("B");
    add("C");
}};
```

but as you can see it is not easy to read. If you use a static block instead

```
  static ArrayList<String> test;
  static {
        test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("a");
        test.add("b");
        test.add("c");
    }
```

or as in your question have

```
static ArrayList<String> test;
static {
  foo();
}

private static void foo() {
    test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("a");
    test.add("b");
    test.add("c");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A static class member means it can be called without having an instance of a variable.

e.g.

```
class my_class
{
    static void my_static_function()
    { 
    // whatever
    }
}
```

You can call it in both ways:

```
my_class::my_static_function();

my_class m;
m.my_static_function();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a **static initializer block**, which are used for initializing static variables. These are run once for the life of a class (not each time you create an instance). For  example, you may want to populate a static data structure in a way that can't be done usually.

There are also **non-static initializer blocks**. These are run every time an instance is created. They're often used to initialize the variables of anonymous classes. It's useful to know that these execute before the constructor.

```
class BlockTest {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static block.");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Non-static block.");
    }

    public BlockTest() {
        System.out.println("Constructor.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BlockTest();
    }
}
```

This code will output the following:

```
Static block.
Non-static block.
Constructor.
```